# events_create fails in facebook

Tags: facebook

strugglin to create event in javascript as

```
api.events_create(eventInfo,function(result,ex){
```

is failing and

catch(FacebookRestClientException){
gives

TypeError: api.events_create is not a function message=api.events_create is not a function

any clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

api.callMethod works - have put a sample call , hope it helps

```
        var eventInfo = {
            "name":this.name.value,
            "category":"1",
            "subcategory":"2",
            "host":"My Host",
            "location":"JP Nagar",
            "city":"Bang",
            "start_time":starttime,
            "end_time":endtime};

    function createEvent(eventinfo) {
        try{
            //check if user has extended permission to create otherwise prompt him for same
            api.users_hasAppPermission('create_event',function(res,ex){
            if (res == 0)
                FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("create_event", 
                    function(res,ex){alert("Congratulations events");});
            });

            dict = {};
            dict['event_info'] = eventinfo;
            //provide a call back or a sequencer
            var ret = api.callMethod(
                    'events.create', 
                    dict,
                    function(eventid,ex){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            return ret;
        }
        catch(FacebookRestClientException){
            console.log(FacebookRestClientException);
        }
        return;
    }//createEvent routine
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more context would help in debugging this.

You've created the `api` object, yes? (e.g., `var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. If I look at the list of functions attached to FB.Facebook.apiClient using a DOM inspector, events_create() does not exist - even though other methods like events_get() and feed_publishUserAction() are there.

Facebook might have deliberately omitted it.